# Gradient histograms in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, histogram

I am trying to figure out how to create an array of histogram to compare the magnitude and direction of gradient vectors of an image in matlab. I am to use sobel masks to find the gradients, so far I have:

```
sobel_x = [-1 -2 -1;0  0  0;1  2  1];
sobel_y = [-1  0  1;-2  0  2;-1  0  1];

gx = filter2(sobel_x,im,'same');
gy = filter2(sobel_y,im,'same');
```

Now I need to figure out how to create a histogram to compare it with other images.

Comment: Are you asking a question here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can take the computed *gx* and *gy* matrices and treat them as long vectors, then group them into a gradient vector that is size: 2 x (# number of elements in *gx* or *gy*)

```
% create the gradient vectors
    grad_vector(1,:) = gx(:);
    grad_vector(2,:) = gy(:);
```

then you can find the magnitude and direction of each gradient vector in a variety of ways, for example:

```
%find magnitude and direction of each gradient vector
    for i=1:size(grad_vector,2);
       magn(i) = norm(grad_vector(:,i));
       dir(i) = atand(grad_vector(2,i)/grad_vector(1,i));
    end
```

the histogram can then be created by deciding how to divide up the results into a number of bins. For example, you may choose to divide the direction into 4 bins and the magnitude into 3, then:

```
% find histograms, dividing into appropriate bins
    histdir = hist(dir,4);
    histmag = hist(magn,3);
```